# Azure Storage Account stuck on 0% for Data Lake Gen2 validation

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-storage-account

I am trying to upgrade my Azure Storage Account to the Gen2 Data Lake. I am running the 3 step process in the UI, but when I get to step 2 (validation), it just sits at 0% and never progresses. I don't see any errors come up or anything, just no progress and I have left it running for hours.

What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up finding the answer: there were errors, the front-end just wasn't showing them. I went into the containers and there was one for the hns migration, inside was an error.json file with the details.

For me it was some files which had multiple versions.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and for me doing it through the command line ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/upgrade-to-data-lake-storage-gen2-how-to?tabs=azure-cli)) worked.

For Azure CLI that means activating the subscription where you storage account is in and then executing the following command:

```
az storage account hns-migration start --type validation -n <storage-account-name> -g <resource-group-name>
```